# List of all different database tables used in views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to find all the different database tables used in views.
I tried `information_schema.view_table_usage`.
I got results for current database.
But tables associated with different database are not fetching.
Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `information_schema` ([here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)) or `sysdepends` ([here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008)).

```
SELECT v.name, 
  ed.referenced_database_name,
  ed.referenced_schema_name,
  ed.referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.views AS v
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS ed
ON v.[object_id] = ed.referencing_id;
```

If you only want things in another database, add:

```
WHERE ed.referenced_database_name IS NOT NULL;
```

You have to run this query from the context of the database where the view exists.

As an aside, permissions are a little different. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql):

> Requires VIEW DEFINITION permission on the database and SELECT permission on sys.sql_expression_dependencies for the database.

If you don't have these permissions (explicitly, or though `db_owner`/`sysadmin` or a few other roles), you won't get an error message, the view will just return no rows.

[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/view-column-usage-transact-sql), on the other hand, has a little more freedom, but still has the limitation you observed (only returns references within the same database):

> Returns one row for each column in the current database that is used in a view definition. This information schema view returns information about the objects to which the current user has permissions.

In order to use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, you'll need someone to grant you the appropriate permissions, or they'll need to create a stored procedure that calls it, executes as owner, and give you permissions to call that stored procedure.

Comment: Getting blank for Sys.sql_expression_dependencies. Please suggest any alternate .

Comment: @Vinbeatz180 I don't know what "getting blank" means. Are you sure you are in the context of the database with the views? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hi Sir , I am using version 2016

Comment: The above given query proving no result sir .

Comment: @Vinbeatz180 Then you either (a) are calling it from the wrong database, (b) don't have any views, or (c) don't have the right permissions to view dependencies (see [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql): `Requires VIEW DEFINITION permission on the database and SELECT permission on sys.sql_expression_dependencies for the database.` If you don't have these permissions (explicitly or though db_owner/sysadmin or a few other roles), you won't get an error message, the view will just return no rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sys tables [sys.objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [sys.sysdepends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to retrieve the information you as follows

```
--Replace 'YOU VIEW NAME' by the view you want

--1) using old sys tables
select distinct(ov.name),ov.xtype from sysobjects o 
inner join sysdepends d on o.id=d.id 
inner join sysobjects ov on d.depid=ov.id
where o.name='YOUR VIEW NAME'


--2) using new sys.table

select distinct(ov.name),ov.type from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.sysdepends d on o.object_id=d.id 
inner join sys.objects ov on d.depid=ov.object_id
where o.name='YOUR VIEW NAME'
```

Comment: Using above query , I got only the tables associated in the current Db. 
But in View we used different db tables also .

Comment: Can you show me the view code in which you used many dbs